# Locate all similar "touching" elements in a 2D Array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, python-3.5

Let's say I have the array:

```
someArray = [["0","1","1","0"]
             ["0","1","0","1"]
             ["0","1","0","1"]
             ["0","1","1","0"]]
```

I would like to point out one element in the array and then be able to identify every similar "touching" element (touching meaning if the array was viewed as a grid, they would be connected through one or more connections). For example, in this case, if I chose someArray[0][0], it would give me [1][0],[2][0] and [3][0], because all of those elements are "0", and are "touching" one another. I only mean touching NESW, without the combinations of said directions.

What would I need to do to start working on this?

EDIT: This turned out to be simply "Flood Fill".

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: This might help in your research: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: Scipy has some interesting function to accomplish this: [`scipy.ndimage.measurements.label`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html) or [`find_objects`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.find_objects.html#scipy.ndimage.measurements.find_objects)

Comment: Please define your "touching" criteria. If looking at the array as a map having N, E, S, and W directions, do you only include those blocks that are adjacent in those directions? Do you also include blocks directly adjacent in the NE, SE, SW, and NW directions as well? Do you need the ability to define an adjacency matrix to determine neighbours of matrix locations?

Comment: @MarkyPython I don't want to learn exactly how I would do it, I just want to know where to start.

Comment: @Robᵩ Ah, thanks, that is helpful.

Comment: @MSeifert That's also something I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: @NoctisSkytower I'll update the main post, but what you and others have said mostly cover what I'm intending. It was meant to be NESW, without the diagonals.

Comment: Does the added code help at all? I decided to allow the concept of neighbors to be configurable. It would be a simple task to add diagonal membership to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider learning how to implement [breadth-first searches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and [depth-first searches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) in order to accomplish your objective. The following example shows how both of these search strategies can be easily handled in one function. A modular approach should make the code simple to change.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from collections import deque
from operator import eq


def main():
    """Show how to search for similar neighbors in a 2D array structure."""
    some_array = ((0, 1, 1, 0),
                  (0, 1, 0, 1),
                  (0, 1, 0, 1),
                  (0, 1, 1, 0))
    neighbors = (-1, 0), (0, +1), (+1, 0), (0, -1)
    start = 0, 0
    similar = eq
    print(list(find_similar(some_array, neighbors, start, similar, 'BFS')))


def find_similar(array, neighbors, start, similar, mode):
    """Run either a BFS or DFS algorithm based on criteria from arguments."""
    match = get_item(array, start)
    block = {start}
    visit = deque(block)
    child = dict(BFS=deque.popleft, DFS=deque.pop)[mode]
    while visit:
        node = child(visit)
        for offset in neighbors:
            index = get_next(node, offset)
            if index not in block:
                block.add(index)
                if is_valid(array, index):
                    value = get_item(array, index)
                    if similar(value, match):
                        visit.append(index)
        yield node


def get_item(array, index):
    """Access the data structure based on the given position information."""
    row, column = index
    return array[row][column]


def get_next(node, offset):
    """Find the next location based on an offset from the current location."""
    row, column = node
    row_offset, column_offset = offset
    return row + row_offset, column + column_offset


def is_valid(array, index):
    """Verify that the index is in range of the data structure's contents."""
    row, column = index
    return 0 <= row < len(array) and 0 <= column < len(array[row])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, thanks!