# 2D array index positions "touching"

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm looking to find a way to be able to return if positions in a 2d array are both "touching" and similar values, tracing all the way around. Before I get into this there is a very similar question asked, and solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140908/locate-all-similar-touching-elements-in-a-2d-array-python), but it's written in python which I know nothing of. To further expand:

```
f f f f

f T T f

f T T f

f f f f
```

starting at `[0][0]` it would return all the falses in that array because they are the same value and chain back to `[0][0]`.

```
f f f T f f f

f T f T f T f

f f f T f f f
```

but based on this one, starting at `[0][0]` would only return `[0][0,1,2]` , `[1][0,2]` , and `[2][0,1,2]`. however if you were to start at `[0][4]`, it would return all the falses after `[n][3]` because they are the same value as the start, and touching.

Not looking for anyone to help me write code exactly but maybe point me in the right direction. Please excuse my novice level in advance, and thank you very much!

Comment: It's not clear what kind of problem you have. Error? Wrong values returned? Also you have an error with description - `[0][0,1,2]` is mentioned twice

Comment: apologies I was attempting to simplify the writing. that translates to [0][0], [0][1], [0][2]. I was looking for a type of algorithm that handles this or a point in that direction. Dmitry helped me below with a "breadth first search" alg. Thanks!

Comment: This is known as the [Flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have a *graph* problem and you are looking for *Breadth First Search* or alike algorithm where

1. Graph nodes: all valid (`f`) array items
2. Graph edges: if and only if array items are *neighbors*

Implementation:

```
private static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> Touching(char[,] items, 
                                                     Tuple<int, int> startAt, 
                                                     char letter = 'f') {
  if (startAt.Item1 < 0 || startAt.Item1 >= items.GetLength(0) ||
      startAt.Item2 < 0 || startAt.Item2 >= items.GetLength(1))
    yield break; // or throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException
  else if (items[startAt.Item1, startAt.Item2] != letter)
    yield break;

  Queue<Tuple<int, int>> agenda = new Queue<Tuple<int, int>>();
  HashSet<Tuple<int, int>> visited = new HashSet<Tuple<int, int>>() { startAt };

  agenda.Enqueue(startAt);

  while (agenda.Any()) {
    for (int i = agenda.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      var point = agenda.Dequeue();

      yield return point;

      // Manhattan: left, right, top, bottom neighbors only, no diagonal ones
      var validNeighbors = new Tuple<int, int>[] {
         new Tuple<int, int>(point.Item1 - 1, point.Item2),     // left
         new Tuple<int, int>(point.Item1 + 1, point.Item2),     // right
         new Tuple<int, int>(point.Item1, point.Item2 - 1),     // top
         new Tuple<int, int>(point.Item1, point.Item2 + 1),}    // bottom
      .Where(p => p.Item1 >= 0 && p.Item1 < items.GetLength(0)) // Within array
      .Where(p => p.Item2 >= 0 && p.Item2 < items.GetLength(1)) // Within array
      .Where(p => items[p.Item1, p.Item2] == letter)            // valid point
      .Where(p => visited.Add(p));                              // not visited 

      foreach (var p in validNeighbors)
        agenda.Enqueue(p);
    }
  }
}
```

Test:

```
 char[,] data = new char[,] {
    { 'f', 'f', 'f', 'T', 'f', 'f', 'f',},
    { 'f', 'f', 'f', 'T', 'f', 'f', 'f',},
    { 'f', 'f', 'f', 'T', 'f', 'f', 'f',},
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    Touching(data, new Tuple<int, int>(0, 0), 'f'));

  Console.WriteLine(report);
```

Outcome (all these items below are touching i.e. *reachable* from the `startAt` point - `(0, 0)`):

```
(0, 0)
(1, 0)
(0, 1)
(2, 0)
(1, 1)
(0, 2)
(2, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 2)
```

With a help of *Linq* you can organize the report in different way (like in the question):

```
var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
  Touching(data, new Tuple<int, int>(0, 0), 'f')
    .GroupBy(item => item.Item1, item => item.Item2)
    .OrderBy(chunk => chunk.Key)
    .Select(chunk => $"[{chunk.Key}][{string.Join(", ", chunk.OrderBy(x => x))}]"));
```

And have the response below:

```
[0][0, 1, 2]
[1][0, 1, 2]
[2][0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much. This is absolutely perfect and very informative.